# Why a tube light is going bad on a particular fixture every now and then

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, led, light

As you can see two tube lights are there in terrace under the shade of tin-can shed.

Both the tube light's energy supply is handled by one switch but the tube light that I attach in the particular fixture needs changing once in 6 months.It simply goes bad.

Any ideas why this happens with this particular one and how to stop this from happening in future ?

[image]

The freelancing electrician told me that he could find nothing wrong. It's simply a bad co-incidence.

But I find this explanation hard to buy because it can't be happening frequently.

Update:

Please find information about the light.

[image]

[image]

Comment: LEDs or florescence?  If florescence have you changed starters or ballast?

Comment: Is the fixture rated for an outdoor installation? They may have both been installed properly, then one went bad and was replaced with a cheap indoor-only rated fixture. Even though there's a roof over this, it's considered a wet location and needs an appropriately rated fixture.

Comment: @FreeMan - it's from phillips and it's not specifically marked as either indoor or outdoor but I can say both the tube lights are same. In my locality after 10 PM more power will come to home , This we can know just by seeing brightness difference before 10 PM and after 10 PM. I noticed this tube light go bad when I used it after 10 PM once.

Comment: If it's not _explicitly_ marked for outdoor use, it's probably not designed for that. Do you see any markings on the other fixture? Are they different? Where in the world are you - rules & regulations (and product availability) vary...

Comment: Fluorescent lamps have hot filaments that eventually break. Similar looking LED replacements can last for 10 or 20 years. One *caveat:* you state the power varies. If so, be sure to install overvoltage protection, e.g., similar to one of these, *but appropriate for your use*: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=overvoltage+protection . They help prevent damage and fires.

Comment: @FreeMan - It's marked as indoor,outdoor.Please find my updated question

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - it's just a general observation , after 10 PM the lights are usually brighter and fans rotate bit faster. My residence have both RCD and GFCI. I'm planning to invest on SDP(Surge Device Protection) for whole building and CAFCI for arc protection. Mostly because my garage has upto 8 motorcycles , car and the electrical main supply is also on the garage only.Do I still have to invest on over voltage protection ? you mean voltage stabiliser for whole residence right ?